# How do I place a transistor in circuitikz so that its collector (or any particular node) is at a given coordinate?

Tags: circuitikz

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)
node[transformer] (T) {};

\draw (T.B1)
to [D] (3,|-T.B1)
to [R] (3,|-T.B2)
-- (T.B2);

{
\ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/width =0.4}
\draw (3,|-T.B1)
to [vR] (6,|-T.B1)
to [R] (6,-1);
}

\draw (3,-1)
node [npn,xscale=-1] (npn) {} 
(npn.collector) ;

\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I place the transistor's collector at the end of the rightmost resistor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the anchors for the collector (the `circuitikz` documentation explains the predefined anchors for the components but, in this case, you could also use "standard" TikZ anchors):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)
node[transformer] (T) {};

\draw (T.B1)
to [D] (3,|-T.B1)
to [R] (3,|-T.B2)
-- (T.B2);

{
\ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/width =0.4}
\draw (3,|-T.B1)
to [vR] (6,|-T.B1)
to [R] 
(6,-1) node [npn,xscale=-1,anchor=C] (npn) {} 
(npn.collector);
}
\end{circuitikz}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0)
node[transformer] (T) {};

\draw (T.B1)
to [D] (3,|-T.B1)
to [R] (3,|-T.B2)
-- (T.B2);

{
\ctikzset{bipoles/resistor/width =0.4}
\draw (3,|-T.B1)
to [vR] (6,|-T.B1)
to [R] (6,-1);
}

\draw (6,-1)
  node [npn,xscale=-1,anchor=B,rotate=-90] (npn) {} 
  (npn.collector);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You.
How do I place it so that its emmiter is also at the same height as the transformer's lower baseline (anchor B2)?

Comment: Like this? `\draw to (6,-1|-T.B2)
  node [npn,xscale=-1,anchor=east,rotate=-90] (npn) {} 
  (npn.collector) to (T.B2-|3,-2);
\draw (aux) -- (npn.B);` Sorry, but since I'm not familiar with those components I have no idea which node is the collector and which is the emmiter, but the code above should give you the idea.

Comment: I am little confused with this coordinate (6,-1|-T.B2).
can you help with this?

Comment: @RajBatra Sure! `(<coordinatea>|-<coordinateb>)` is the point with the x-coordinate of `<coordinatea>` and the y-coordinate of `<coordinateb>` so, for example, `(3,2|-4,5)` is nothing more than `(3,5)`.

Comment: @YogeshYadav Did my comment help you? Or were you asking for something different and I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Yes. It did help me. I am sorry I completely forgot to acknowledge your help. Thank You.

Comment: @YogeshYadav No need for that :) I just wanted to make sure that my comment was really addressing your question. Don't forget that around here, accepting answers is the preferred way of thanking people ;)